# Filter the results not replace them?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am working on a google Map Api using fusion. I have multiple search queries and want them to filter the results. At the moment they overrule each other and don't work together the filter the results. The site is called [earthquakedamagemap.com](http://www.earthquakedamagemap.com/). It is my university project. Any help would be much appreciated.

I think it is the 'value.replace' attribute which needs changing?

```
    function changeMap2() { 
      var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string2').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");  
      if(!searchString) {
        layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid);
        return;
      }
      layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Updated Risk Assessment:' = '" + searchString + "'");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted some example code:
[in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399777/how-do-i-build-more-than-1-drop-down-selector-menu-on-the-same-table-layer-in-go) not too long ago.  You need to combine your search conditions with AND and call layer.setQuery with multiple search conditions only once.  I don't think it has anything to do with your replace call as I didn't see any embedded single quotes in your input values.

Eric

Comment: Thank you for your post Eric. Could you be a little more specific. How do you combine search conditions with AND, and which 'layer.setQuery' do I add the multiple search conditions to?

Comment: Hi James, layer.setQuery() is deprecated.  I use layer.setOptions() as my sample code shows.  But the idea is the same:  where 'some_property' = 'some_value' AND 'some_other_property' = 'some_other_value' AND 'some_number_property' = NNNN.  Is that clear?

Comment: Can I get you to write the code for a donation? I know i'm close, once I see it i'll understand.

Comment: No donation needed.  I've fixed your app and added some comments. Can you send me your email?  Mine is in my profile.