# Inner query in fusion tables

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

This query will take input from three drop down box and a text box and it work's fine as expected.But my requirement is i need  to use another three drop down box and a text in order to query much deeper.So,i need to hold the result of first query and also second query.How should i do.Help me.

```
     That another three drop down box value is also obtained from the same variable's as 'operator','textvalue','querypass'.

function querymap()
        {
        var operator=document.getElementById('operatorstring').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var textvalue=document.getElementById("text-value").value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var querypass=document.getElementById('query-pass').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var searchStringe = document.getElementById('Search-stringe').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
            {

              layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypass + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypass + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "' AND VillageName = '"+ searchStringe+"'");

            }


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the expected result? You want to use the result of your query for a subsequent query?

Comment: yes,,i want to use the result of my first query to the second query...

Comment: Your code implies that you use FusionTablesLayer, and this means that you don't actually get the result of a query, you just display it on a map. Maybe you can describe what exactly you want to do. Why do you need to use the result of the first query?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many AND conditions in your query as you want. No reason not to also check e.g. textvalue2, querypass2, searchString2, etc. and add them to your query.  See this [setQuery() answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9401345/1211981) which may give you some ideas.  You'll need to set all your search conditions each time you call layer.setQuery() or layer.setOptions({query: ...});

Comment: If i add 'AND' condition like this.Will it works.But it gives me error .I think some quotation is wrong.Please help me.                layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypass + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypass + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "' AND VillageName = '"+ searchStringe+ "' AND hhSanitToiletHome=FALSE '"'");

Comment: Finally I got the output..Thank you so much Eric Bridger